# Why is Matlab 2D attaching a raw with different size into a matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, parsing, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have an empty matrix and I have a for loop, in each iteration, I want to add a raw to this matrix, each raw comes with a different size. How can I do that?

I have the following code: bag.resetView(topic5);

```
 mxdata = [][] ;
    mydata = [][] ;
    while bag.hasNext();
    [msg5, meta] = bag.read();
    for i=1: length(msg5.markers)
         mxdata = [ mxdata msg5.markers.pose.position(1)] ;
         // we add a raw, next time we should add the seconf raw for this matrix 
    end
 end
```

=======================================================

the modified code according to the answer provided by Naven but still not solved

```
size_topic_3 = bag.readAll({topic3});

bag.resetView(topic3);
count = 0;
s3time = [] ;
mcxdata = cell(length(size_topic_3),1);
mcydata = cell(length(size_topic_3),1);
mczdata = cell(length(size_topic_3),1);
while bag.hasNext();
   [msg, meta] = bag.read();

s3time = [ s3time msg.header.stamp.time] ;
for i=1:length(msg.points)
    mcxdata{i} =  msg.points(1);
    mcydata{i} =  msg.points(2);
    mczdata{i} =  msg.points(3);
 end
```

end

the output I got is one column.. Also, the column some times has a value and sometime an empty array ?? I want is as raws

Answer (score 0):

Try using a cell array if the size of the `raw` varies in the loop. Here is how you can do that:

```
mxdata = cell(length(msg5.markers),1);
while bag.hasNext();
      [msg5, meta] = bag.read();
      for i=1: length(msg5.markers)
          mxdata{i} = mxdata msg5.markers.pose.position(1) ;
      end
end
```

Each cell in the `mxdata` accommodates the `raw` values. I hope this is what you want to do. If you can provide sample data, I shall be able to provide more specific solution.

Comment: I tried this but it concatenate all the data as a colomn. So, instead of having a matrix of 2D I got one colomn

Comment: @TravellingSalesWoman I think you got a cell array of dimension `x * 1`. each cell contains the two dimensional `raw` matrix. Once you get the result, please check the contents of each cell of the cell array. If I did not understand your comment correctly, please send me some sample data. I shall let you know how you can get the expected result.